# asp .net core ControllerBase.Challange

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid

Стоит задача, написать свой IdentityServer используя библиотеку OpenIdDict. Во всех примерах, при авторизации пользователя (пример по [ссылке](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOpeniddict/blob/9b7bb2fb3eec4070213cc3d426234d803ef08ce3/OpeniddictServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs#LL73C24-L73C24)), используется метод "Challange" (с я которым ранее не работал). Данный метод перенаправляет пользователя на страницу ввода логина и пароля, согласно заданной политики авторизации приложения, однако где именно прописывается Uri для конкретной политики?

В качестре реалзации данной страницы, планируется использовать не Razor Pages как в примерах, а стороннее приложение на ангуляре. Подскажите, где именно происходит конфигурация политики авторизации с указанием ссылки на которую будет перенаправлен пользователь ?

Comment: Такое обычно настраивается в стартовой точке, где прописываются все сервисы. Например [вот](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOpeniddict/blob/9b7bb2fb3eec4070213cc3d426234d803ef08ce3/OpeniddictServer/Startup.cs#L151). Такое у проекта есть [пошаговый гайд](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/11/implementing-openid-implicit-flow-using-openiddict-and-angular/), в котором прописано как и что делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ На сколько я понял, это задание стандартного ендпоинта для Open Id Connect куа перенаправляются пользователи клиентских приложений. Мне же не совсем понятно как сконфигурирован данный пример, что после направления на данный эндпоинт и выдова метода Chalange из этого самого ендпоинта, открывается UI авторизации (https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOpeniddict/blob/9b7bb2fb3eec4070213cc3d426234d803ef08ce3/OpeniddictServer/Views/Authorization/Authorize.cshtml#LL2C1-L2C26)

Comment: Межна ли как то сконфигурировать метод Challange что бы он перенаправлял пользоватля по иному пути ? Как вариант можно использовать редирект, но в примерах от чего то именно Challange всегда используется

Comment: "стандартного для Open Id" - а чем стандартный отличается от предложенного вами? Там даже картинка схожа, что говорит нам о чем? Верно, о том, что автор предложенной вами библиотеки сделал обертку над стандартным OpenId, дописав туда разные "плюшки". А это в свою очередь означает, что там половина работает так-же, как и в стандартном, и стоит изучить сначала стандартную библиотеку, а затем уже использовать кастом. Касательно редиректа, ссылку, что вы дали в вопросе - там есть прям `RedirectUri`, его и переопределяйте если надо. Больше увы, сказать не могу.